# Unable to call Azure search for specific asp.net .netframework 4.7.1 project (RequestFailedException)

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have a asp.net 4.7.1 project (upgraded to 4.7.1 during last 6-7 years) and I' not able to connect/call any method in Azure Searchc from within that project. I'm getting a RequestFailedException (Complete log at end)

Unfortunatly can I not reproduce in new Console app, new Asp.net 4.7.1 project!

I'm running all types of projects on same machine in same Visual Studio 2022.

I'm calling the Search service with the exact same code and same version of Nuget (11.3.0). (I have tried earlier versions as well 11.1.1, but same error).
I'm using the same service/index and key (Currently just a free service, but doesn't make any different if I run against other)

My testcode is:

```
var searchIndexClient = new SearchIndexClient(new 
Uri($"https://sfsearchtest.search.windows.net"),
new AzureKeyCredential("70C978F2751C051E0BF156B0....."),
options);
noIndexes = searchIndexClient.GetIndexes().Count();
```

(I've obfuscated the key here)

It does not matter if I try callanothr method then "GetIndexes". Same error.
Note I have set MaxRetries = 0; But more retries gives same error so I have turned down to 0 retries.

Help really appreciated after a couple of days frustration/testing. And please do not ask me to update project to .Netcore ;-)

I have made a file compare between the ddls for "my project" compared to a newly created 4.7.1 project and they are exactly the same files.

Here is an error log (from AzureEventSourceListener.CreateConsoleLogger and

```
AzureEventSourceListener.CreateTraceLogger).

Azure-Core: [Informational] Request [916938f7-cc37-483b-a134-33ca2c69d22b] GET https://sfsearchtest.search.windows.net/indexes?$select=*&api-version=2020-06-30
Accept:application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
api-key:REDACTED
x-ms-client-request-id:916938f7-cc37-483b-a134-33ca2c69d22b
x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
User-Agent:azsdk-net-Search.Documents/11.3.0 (.NET Framework 4.8.4420.0; Microsoft Windows 10.0.19044 )
client assembly: Azure.Search.Documents
Azure-Core: [Informational] Request [916938f7-cc37-483b-a134-33ca2c69d22b] GET https://sfsearchtest.search.windows.net/indexes?$select=*&api-version=2020-06-30
Accept:application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
api-key: REDACTED
x-ms-client-request-id:916938f7-cc37-483b-a134-33ca2c69d22b
x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
User-Agent:azsdk-net-Search.Documents/11.3.0 (.NET Framework 4.8.4420.0; Microsoft Windows 10.0.19044 )
client assembly: Azure.Search.Documents
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'Azure.RequestFailedException' in Azure.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'Azure.RequestFailedException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Azure.RequestFailedException' in mscorlib.dll
Azure-Core: [Informational] Request [916938f7-cc37-483b-a134-33ca2c69d22b] exception Azure.RequestFailedException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpWebRequestTransport.<ProcessInternal>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpWebRequestTransport.Process(HttpMessage message)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.ProcessNextAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.<ProcessAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.LoggingPolicy.<ProcessAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
Azure-Core: [Informational] Request [916938f7-cc37-483b-a134-33ca2c69d22b] exception Azure.RequestFailedException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpWebRequestTransport.<ProcessInternal>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpWebRequestTransport.Process(HttpMessage message)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.ProcessNextAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.<ProcessAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.Process(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelinePolicy.ProcessNext(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.LoggingPolicy.<ProcessAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
Exception thrown: 'Azure.RequestFailedException' in Azure.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'Azure.RequestFailedException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Azure.RequestFailedException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Azure.RequestFailedException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Azure.RequestFailedException' in Azure.Search.Documents.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I managed to solve it. Short answer for now:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

The Tls have caused problems before. Not sure why my old project causes problems with this (could not find anything about tls). Luckely this worked :)